# Is it safe? Where to put the fuse?

Tags: power-electronics

I want to build connection like this. Is it safe? I want to put fuse in the circuit. Where should I put the fuses before or after converter?

There is no any fuses in the system yet. I am using this converter (sunsky-online.com/product/…) I use 30A model and (continental.sg/step-down/products/…). For wiring from battery I use 12AWG wire for 30A converter and 16AWG wire for 12A converter.

Thank You. 
[image]

Comment: Are there any fuses anywhere in the system already? Do you have a schematic for the converter? Or a manufacturer and part number? Can you show what wire size you are using for all the connections?

Comment: @mkeith There is no any fuses in the system yet. I am using this converter (https://www.sunsky-online.com/product/default!view.do?subject.itemNo=S-TC-7003) I use 30A model and (http://www.continental.sg/step-down/products/dc-dc-step-down-buck-converter-7-32v-to-0-8-28v-300w-12a). For wiring from battery I use 12AWG wire for 30A converter and 16AWG wire for 12A converter.

Comment: Put the fuse in series with the battery.  Better yet, use a Lithium battery protection circuit.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, please put the information in the question. In other words, edit the question and add the information so that it is more accessible and people don't have to read through the comments to find it.

Comment: @mkeith thank you. I have edited the questions.  Do you have suggestion for any protection circuit that I can use? Thanks

Comment: @NickAlexeev Thanks. Any suggestion for circuit protection?

Comment: What are you wanting the fuse to protect?

Answer (score 1):

You need fuses as follows :

1) in the supply cable from the battery

And

2) in each supply to the loads ie 1 for the vacuum, the other for the controller.

These fuses need to be rated for the demands at those points.

Comment: Thank you. While vacuum motor draws 20A from battery, will it affect micro controller?

Comment: You may need to add a filter capacitor at the Vin of the microcontroller. If it's a module it should have one already. If it's an ic you have to add it. Since it's on a separate converter there will be less problems already.

Comment: In fact you can put fuses anywhere: before, after, in between, at each new branch. Here it's a good idea to use separate fuses for the vacuum and the micro because they have different currents. Therefore after the converters. One just after the battery will make sure there is no problem between the battery and the other fuses.