# One lipo battery to supply multiple circuit boards

Tags: power-electronics, lipo

I want to supply all my circuit boards with one lipo battery. The design is like this. [image]

I need a battery connector cable. So, I made my own battery Y-cable like this.

[image]

I use XT-90 connector to connect to lipo battery and xt-60 connector for 3 boards. When I connect my vaccum motor, it couldn't run the motor. Is there any problems in the cables? I use 12AWG for XT-90 Connector and 16AWG for XT-60 connector. Is there any connector for this use?

Is the resistance from all wire and connector caused the problem that cannot turn on motor?

The battery is onbo Lipo 6s 22.2 v 22000mAh 25C

Thanks all.

[Converter for Vacuum Motor](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Real-SUVPR-car-30a-DC24V-to-DC12V-negative-booster-step-down-transformer-pressure-reducer-360w-power/32319466339.html?spm=2114.10010108.1000013.2.79411e818OoyGe&scm=1007.13339.90158.0&scm_id=1007.13339.90158.0&scm-url=1007.13339.90158.0&pvid=33bbd0e9-c63c-4c8c-b825-e4e05c85b066&_t=pvid:33bbd0e9-c63c-4c8c-b825-e4e05c85b066,scm-url:1007.13339.90158.0)
[Converter for Up Board](http://sg.element14.com/mean-well/rsd-60g-5/dc-dc-converter-5v-6a/dp/2816125?ost=2816125&ddkey=http%3Aen-SG%2FElement14_Singapore%2Fsearch)
[Converter for controller board](http://sg.element14.com/mean-well/rsd-60l-12/dc-dc-converter-12v-2-5a/dp/2816130?ost=2816130&ddkey=http%3Aen-SG%2FElement14_Singapore%2Fsearch)

Comment: what's the max current your battery can provide? I see about 17A that it needs to provide if everything is on (not accounting for conversion losses).

Comment: Lipo battery can provide 22A for one hour. And it have 25C discharge rate.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/378525/152903

Comment: @SolarMike I cannot turn on the motor. I haven't put the fuses in the circuit yet.

Comment: What step-down converters have you used? Please provide a data sheet link for the battery.

Comment: @Andyaka I edited the questions to include converters link. Thanks

Comment: Negative booster?! do you by any chance connect all the grounds together past DC-DC outputs? It is not on your circuit btw.